# Is it possible to create Spring OAuth2 Client without web-app environment?

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

The actual use case is calling service protected by oauth2 from spark master. Starting http server for this (as @EnableOAuth2Client assumes) looks like an overhead. Does anybody know how to implement oauth2 client without starting web server?

Comment: The moment someone asked your exact question but didn't get an answer... did you solve it meanwhile?

Comment: yes and no: for my PoC spark job I solved it by adding `spring.main.web-environment=false` in application.properties, but it must be a better solution